# Django dynamic localization not working as expected on mobile devices

Tags: django, mobile, django-templates

I have question about show current language on mobile devices if I populate my language list in template dynamically (got from languages array from settings)...
So, this code working properly:

```
<a href="#" id="language-en" class="pure-drawer-link{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %} active{% endif %}"> EN </a>
```

BUT, when I'm trying this code, I can't achive that `active` class added to current language:

```
{% for lng in settings.LANGUAGES %}
                                    {% if not lng.0 == "ru" %}
                                        <a href="#" id="language-{{ lng.0 }}"
                                           class="pure-drawer-link{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == '{{ lng.0 }}' %} active{% endif %}">
                                            {{ lng.0|upper }}
                                        </a>
                                        {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == '{{ lng.0 }}' %} active {% else %} nonactive{% endif %} => this always return nonactive
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone help to understood why this is happening?

**EDIT 1:**

My middlewars in settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'my_app.middleware.ExpirationMiddleware',
    'my_app.middleware.IPMiddleware',
    'my_app.middleware.TranslationMiddleware',
   ]
```

and this for i18:

```
USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Zurich'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
```